# What prompts a get method to return HTML instead of the json data it's supposed to return when fetching api from ASP.NET Core MVC to reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create an app where the frontend on the client side is made with react.js and the backend uses ASP.Net Core MVC. I'm trying to fetch the data from the api for rendering all the data for that table, but instead of a json file it's returning an html file.

This is the react code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AllBlogCard } from '../components/AllBlogCard.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';

const PostsPage = () => {
  const [blogPosts, setBlogPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/BlogApi/List');
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log('blog data:', data);
          setBlogPosts(data);
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to fetch blog posts');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h2 className="section-heading text-center mb-4">All Blog Posts</h2>

          {blogPosts.map((post, index) => (
            <AllBlogCard key={index} {...post} />
          ))}

          <div className="text-center mt-4">
            <button className="btn customBtn my-5">View More Posts<i className="bi bi-arrow-down m-1"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostsPage;
```

This is the backend API method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BlogApiController : ControllerBase
{
     private readonly BloggieDbContext _context;
     private readonly IBlogPostRepo blogPostRepo;

     public BlogApiController(IBlogPostRepo blogPostRepo, BloggieDbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
         this.blogPostRepo = blogPostRepo;
     }

     [HttpGet("List")]
     [Produces("application/json")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> ListApi()
     {
         var blogPosts = await blogPostRepo.GetAllAsync();
         return Ok(blogPosts);
     }
}
```

For context, the blogpost repo is from a repository pattern folder and it has the `DbContext` and everything necessary to properly render the data.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch from this api endpoint in postman?

Comment: @DION23 yes, it returns an html file

Comment: What is the returned HTML? Is content something you would expected or just an error?

Comment: @OzanBAYRAM it's the index.html page that react generates

Comment: I  wonder "How you API is returning the index.html of your react app"? That sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need to do. Set "Content-Type" in the header to "application/json"

You may test it via Postman as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly of all, your code in react app and controller should be correct as I test with them, everything worked well.

[image]

The controller I used is listed below, as you can see, I just return a list of model to mock the response of your `blogPostRepo.GetAllAsync();`.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("List")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListApi()
    {
        var a = new List<Data> { 
            new Data{ 
                id = 1,
                room = "room1"
            },
            new Data{
                id = 2,
                room = "room2"
            }
        };
        return Ok(a);
    }
}
```

Based on my experience, when I got html content instead of the expected data result from an MVC controller, it always because I didn't pass the authentication so that the app would redirect me to the login page.

I'm not sure if you are facing the same issue, my action plan is that you might **visit the API through the browser since it's a get request then see what the html contains**. If this a login page, then you might make a mistake to add the authentication scheme, for API it should return 401 error instead of redirect to sign in page.

By the way, I also want to confirm that if there's exception inside your api, adding break point to debug the project is helpful if there's exception inside it.

Comment: I do have a login functionality and I haven't implemented any authorization yet, so I'm guessing that isn't the problem. The html that I'm getting is actually the index.html that React.js generates with create-react-app

Comment: @hosejojo you mean you use `const response = await fetch('/api/BlogApi/List');` and get the index page as the response? and if you visit the api url `/api/BlogApi/List` in the browser, you will find the browser loads the index page? It's really amazing...

Comment: could you please comment the line `var blogPosts = await blogPostRepo.GetAllAsync();` and using a mock list like what I have then test the api inside browser to see if you would  get the same index page? I can't understand why you would get index page as response from `return OK();`

Comment: not the browser, the

Comment: My action plan: using mock data to replace the `await blogPostRepo.GetAllAsync();` so that we could make sure that the API is correct, then test the API in the browser to see if it returned correct data since it's a get request. Then test the API via your react code and see if you could get the json data. If not, then it's your react code issue, pls share more details about your react app since your code snippet worked well in my side. If you could get the correct json, then I deduce that it's your API issue, you could debug the `await blogPostRepo.GetAllAsync();` to see if there's exception

Comment: inside the API, then replicate the same process to see if the API worked and if the client app could get correct response.